# Load zip content (function executes 2 times)

Tags: node-red

I want to get the contents of the zip file with func node with the following content, but I don't know why this node does it twice.

Where did I go wrong? Please tell me!

```
var JSZip = global.get('JSZip');
var zip = new JSZip()
msg.isOK = false;

zip.loadAsync(msg.payload).then(function () {
    // read files
    const promises = [];
    zip.forEach(function (path, zFile) {
        promises.push(zFile.async('string').then(function (content) {
            return {
                filename: path,
                payload: content
            };
        }));
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(function (files) {
    // send the result
    msg.payload = files;
    msg.isOK = true;
    send(msg);
    done();
}).catch(function (err) {
});

return msg;
```

[image: Image Description]

Flow:

```
[{"id":"7f6426e8.808bb8","type":"file in","z":"f63ce9bd.5c0d28","name":"","filename":"","format":"","chunk":false,"sendError":false,"encoding":"none","x":3710,"y":140,"wires":[["679b95b2.ce366c"]]},{"id":"c1e50527.9abf88","type":"change","z":"f63ce9bd.5c0d28","name":"DataTest.zip","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"filename","pt":"msg","to":"D:\\Work\\DataTest.zip","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":3570,"y":140,"wires":[["7f6426e8.808bb8"]]},{"id":"679b95b2.ce366c","type":"function","z":"f63ce9bd.5c0d28","name":"Load Zip Content","func":"// variable declaration\nvar JSZip = global.get('JSZip');\nvar zip = new JSZip()\nmsg.isOK = false;\n\nzip.loadAsync(msg.payload).then(function () {\n    // read files\n    const promises = [];\n    zip.forEach(function (path, zFile) {\n        promises.push(zFile.async('string').then(function (content) {\n            return {\n                filename: path,\n                payload: content\n            };\n        }));\n    });\n\n    return Promise.all(promises);\n}).then(function (files) {\n    // send the result\n    msg.payload = files;\n    msg.isOK = true;\n    send(msg);\n    done();\n}).catch(function (err) {\n});\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":3870,"y":140,"wires":[["2b710ce5.651694"]]},{"id":"7ebcebca.c16d84","type":"inject","z":"f63ce9bd.5c0d28","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"str","x":3430,"y":140,"wires":[["c1e50527.9abf88"]]},{"id":"f941bb77.168fb8","type":"debug","z":"f63ce9bd.5c0d28","name":"Error","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":4150,"y":200,"wires":[]},{"id":"2b710ce5.651694","type":"switch","z":"f63ce9bd.5c0d28","name":"","property":"isOK","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"true"},{"t":"else"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":2,"x":4030,"y":140,"wires":[["b719c021.92cbe"],["f941bb77.168fb8"]]},{"id":"b719c021.92cbe","type":"debug","z":"f63ce9bd.5c0d28","name":"OK","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":4150,"y":80,"wires":[]}]
```

[DataTest.zip](https://www.mediafire.com/file/16bdg0bg8rj8ped/DataTest.zip/file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling both `send(msg)` and `return msg`

This will mean that you send 2 messages from the function node and since NodeJS/JavaScript is pass by reference they will both end up with the same content.

Best option is just to remove the `return msg` from the end of the function.